# APK file (api 16) run on Android Pie

Tags: android, apk, android-4.2-jelly-bean, android-9.0-pie

I have tried using apk editors to change the target api of the app from jellybean to pie but when downloading onto my note 9 the unedited file tells me it's too old but the edited file doesn't even get to the permissions and simply exits/disappears.

I'd absolutely love to be able to play The Smiler on my phone and this was honestly already way over my head when I allowed apps from sources other than the play store so I'm surrendering.

The Smiler file:
https://the-smiler.en.uptodown.com/android

Thank you
<3

Comment: Crudely modding APK you haven't made is not a valid question

Comment: I guess my question is: what edits do I need to make / tools to use to make the app work? Are there work-arounds like previous-version emulators that can run as their own app on the note 9? Or am I barking up the wrong tree? I've searched for a version that runs on Pie but it seems nobody else has wanted the app to run on newer versions of android although I can safely assume I'm not the first person to want an old android app to run on new versions so I know it can be done. Apologies for not making these questions explicit in my post <3